# In Laravel 4 , In users table all data of this table are removed automatically every day

Tags: laravel-4

[image]

I m using laravel 4, i m just beginner in laravel 4 and stared project in laravel but my issue in users table , all thing working ok like user registration and login auth , but everyday the data of this users table are deleted automatically. please help me to solved this issue.Here i have attached my users table schema.

Comment: So they're unintentionally being deleted?

Comment: yes and it self being deleted. i worked today and if i will see tomorrow all user table data will be deleted tomorrow automatically.

Comment: Are you by any chance using Vagrant and Homestead?

Comment: I have just installed larvel 4 using command in lamp and working simply without any database seeding like codeigniter and this is my second app which i have created in laravel 4 in first app all working ok. Vagrant and Homestead i dont know about it. please help me to solved out it.

Comment: Do you have the same problem with other databases / tables?

Comment: No, that is working ok.

Comment: That's really weird. Are there any jobs that run over night that could do such a thing? (cronjob or similar)

Comment: No, i haven't set any cronjobs  or other queries in my local copy as well as on server.

Comment: Does it happen on both? localhost and your server?

Comment: yes, it happen both side localhost and server.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/67602/discussion-between-lukasgeiter-and-ankit).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have an macro running inside of your laravel application. An que job. Please check your code on que jobs.